# Want to refresh page after every 2 seconds without loosing textarea input data and without blinking page & and without annoying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header("Location:login.php");
 }
 include "int/connect.php";
 include "int/functions.php";

 $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 $hash  = $_GET['hash'];
 $time  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 if(isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
 $new_message = $_POST['message'];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages`      VALUES('','$hash','$my_id','$new_message','$time')");
 }
 ?>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/css.css' />
 <?php
 include "int/header.php";
 ?>
 <div id='outerconversation'>
 <div id="heading"> &nbsp &nbsp Conversation</div>
 <div id="innerconversations">
 <?php
 $message_query = mysql_query("SELECT from_id, message,time FROM `messages`      WHERE `group_hash`='$hash' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4");
 while($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)){
 $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
 $message = $run_message['message'];
 $time = $run_message['time'];
 $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT `email`,`username` FROM `users` WHERE      id='$from_id'");
 $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
 $from_email = $run_user['email'];
 $from_username = $run_user['username'];
 echo "<p><div style='margin: 0% 2%; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-left:      4px solid #008298; border-radius: 10px; padding-top: 5px;'><span style='color:      #008298; font-family: arial; padding-left: 10px;'>$from_username</span><span      style='color: #ccc; font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;'> | $from_email</span>     <br/><span style='color: #ccc; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding-     left: 2%;'>$time</span></p>";
 echo "<p><span style='color: #ccc; font-family: arial; padding-left:      4%;'>says: </span><span style='color: #008298; font-family: Segoe UI      Light;'>$message</span></div></p>";
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <form id="chat_form" method='POST'>
 <textarea name='message' placeholder="Type Message..." maxlength="400"      rows='6' cols='145' autofocus></textarea>
 </form>

 <script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var shiftDown = false;
 var chatForm = $("#chat_form");
 var messageBox = chatForm.children("textarea");

 $(document).keypress(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
         if(messageBox.is(":focus") && !shiftDown) {
             e.preventDefault(); // prevent another \n from being entered
             chatForm.submit();
         }
     }
 });

 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 16) shiftDown = true;
 });

 $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 16) shiftDown = false;
 });
 </script>
 </div>
```

I am working on chatting system but I am hardly stuck because when user one send message to second user, the second user cannot receive message until page refresh. I have tried a lot of functions on it but all functions blink page and lose textarea data and also annoy users. User friendly environment is the first priority for the users all functions which I have applied on it, it always annoy users means page blinks, lose textarea data and page refresh which will annoy users when I host my site to server. I want to refresh/reload page without blinking/reloading page and without loosing textarea data. What can I do if am stuck badly. Please any idea.

Comment: make an ajax call to server, keep session alive.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, since you already use jQuery.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyXeOX-uYMc